# Generate Serial Number From a Long String

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, jakarta-ee

I'm developing an application (iOS and Java) which requires a part to generate serial number as well as reading it from user input.

My output encrypted string looks alike a hex data (long string) like this :

```
"397cf2dbcb034c6c8e63120a211a78f1a628cfa2b36692b5efd3aff93219ca9457bde99765eab793a2f2be183082a702"
```

Obviously this is very difficult for users to read and re-type. I'm looking for a solution to generate a serial number type string ( like this: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx ) from the above string. (I have to be able to decode the serial number and retrieve back the long string inside the app)

Comment: Your encrypted string has 48 bytes. I don't think that you can convert that to 16 alphanumeric characters without losing information.

Comment: Exactly, that's not possible because of the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: So, what kind of encryption should adopt to achieve that?

Comment: @Danialzo: Representing 48 bytes of data with 16 alphanumerical characters is mathematically impossible. Is your serial number really a "serial number" or does it contain data, which is encrypted? If it is a serial number, why is it so long?

Answer (score 0):

How about Base-64 encoding?  That's going to be about as good as you're going to get.  Here's the encoding of that data in base-64:

```
echo "397cf2dbcb034c6c8e63120a211a78f1a628cfa2b36692b5efd3aff93219ca9457bde99765eab793a2f2be183082a702" | xxd -r -p | base64

OXzy28sDTGyOYxIKIRp48aYoz6KzZpK179Ov+TIZypRXvemXZeq3k6LyvhgwgqcC
```

Answer (score 0):

Must you use that large hash function?   Given it's just a serial number, can you use something smaller -- something like a 128bit hash?   That, even in hex, is reasonable, and in base 64, is very reasonable.  With base-64, you'd get a 128-bit key with a form of xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx